# Магнит в Unity - как уменьшить количество GetComponent?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю в Unity магнит - через PhysicsOverlap находим, ищем rigidbody и притягиваем к себе. Код

```
public float radiusdal;
public float forcedal;


void FixedUpdate() {

    Collider[] coldal = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radiusdal);


    foreach (var col1 in coldal)
    {
        if (col1.GetComponent<Rigidbody>())

        {
            var ux = Vector3.Distance(transform.position,  col1.transform.position);
            var aux = 0.5f / (ux); 


            col1.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce((transform.position - col1.transform.position)* aux*  forcedal, ForceMode.Acceleration);

        }}}}
```

Проблема - в коде много GetComponent, и когда на карте больше одного rigidbody - он безбожно тормозит. Как нибудь можно этого избежать? Думается, можно найти все объекты на сцене, вычленить из них те, которые rigidbody, засунуть их в массив. Ну а что дальше? Нам же нужны столкновения, вернее пересечения границы Overlap, а что сделаешь с массивом?

Или пойти другим каким нибудь путем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У каждого collider есть ссылка на rigidbody к которому он привязан [Collider.attachedRigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-attachedRigidbody.html). Так что нет нужды получать ссылку через `GetComponent`

Comment: К сожалению, это не повысило производительность. Но работает!

Comment: покажите какой у вас код в итоге?

Comment: Вот он.
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564812/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-unity-c?noredirect=1
 По факту, через небольшое время, код с attachedRigidbody перестал тормозить. Практически вообще. Так что всё таки - работает.

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном коде можно уменьшить количество вызовов GetComponent<> как минимум в 2 раза.

```
foreach (var col1 in coldal)
{
    Rigidbody colRB = col1.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    if (colRB != null)
    {
        var ux = Vector3.Distance(transform.position,  col1.transform.position);
        var aux = 0.5f / (ux); 

        colRB.AddForce((transform.position - col1.transform.position)* aux*  forcedal, ForceMode.Acceleration);

    }
}
```

Если не ошибаюсь, то обращение к transform через точку, это тот-же GetComponent. Тогда и больше можно ускорить, просто закешировав и все трансформы тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Если элементов много, а магнит один(мало), то пусть объекты проверяются сами на столкновение.  И только те у которых есть rigidbody(проверяй это при создании объекта) А начинают притяжение только при срабатывании события столкновения с коллайдером магнита. Причем магниту вообще не надо знать кто к нему притягивается, а вот объектам нужно знать только позицию магнита и силу притяжения.

> Код (там три этапа притяжения - чем ближе тем сильнее притягивает)

зачем три этапа? Почему просто не вычислить силу притяжения из расстояния

Comment: Благодарю, но было бы отлично более подробный ответ. 

И как вы представляете проверку у каждого объекта ( а их действительно много и они все разные) - в каждый добавлять код для взаимодействия с магнитом? 

Проверять объекты при создании - тоже не панацея, множество объектов расставлены заранее, а вариант с перебором их и занесением в массив я уже озвучил. Ну переберу, ну занесу. А дальше то что? Как взаимодействия с Overlap реализовывать?

Comment: _"И как вы представляете проверку у каждого объекта"_ повесить коллайдеры,    _"множество объектов расставлены заранее"_ Awake в любом случае сработает, или создайте для них общий класс и наследуйте его. _"Ну переберу, ну занесу"_ это излишне

Comment: Ну понятно что повесить коллайдеры. И в скрипте у каждого объекта обозначить его отношения с магнитом, вы это предлагаете? 

За наводку по расстоянию спасибо, гораздо разумнее, чем то что предложил я.

Comment: _" И в скрипте у каждого объекта обозначить его отношения с магнитом, вы это предлагаете? "_ да. Ну я надеюсь есть какой то общий класс родитель для всех объектов, вот в нем и обозначить.

Comment: Для всех объектов кроме магнита? И чтобы были только rigidbody? Нет, такого общего класса родителя у меня нет, слишком избирательно. 
А второй путь с нахождением объектов на сцене и добавлением их в массив - может как то объекты из массива можно будет проверять по Overlap? Или это тупиковый путь?