# Низкая производительность. Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вот такой код(магнит) выдает при включении 2 -3 fps, без него - 70 fps.
При условии что магнит притягивает 2-3 rigidbody. Без объектов рядом вообще не виснет, с одним объектом - 60 fps, с двумя-тремя падает до 3 fps;

```
public class MAGNETO : MonoBehaviour {

        public float radiusdal;
        Transform mytr;
        public float forcedal;




        // Use this for initialization
        void Start() {

            mytr = transform;


        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void FixedUpdate() {


            Collider[] coldal = Physics.OverlapSphere(mytr.position, radiusdal);



            foreach (var col1 in coldal)
            {
        //Вот если этот кусок кода убираем - магнит ничего не притягивает, но и вообще не тормозит.
                if (col1.attachedRigidbody != null) { 
                    var ux = Vector3.Distance(mytr.position,  col1.transform.position);
                    var aux = 0.5f / (ux); 

                    col1.attachedRigidbody.AddForce((mytr.position - col1.transform.position)* aux*  forcedal, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
                }// закончили тормозящий кусок кода.




            }

        }


}
```

`collider.attachedRigidbody` был взят на замену `GetComponent<Rigidbody>`, но результат абсолютно одинаков: 2-3 fps.

Comment: Судя по количеству пробелов в коде - вы что-то вырезали, чтобы не показывать. Но чую загвоздка как-то связана именно не с куском, который вы обозначили комментарием. Или вкупе действует со всем остальным что в других местах написано. От одного такого кода - тормозить не должно

Comment: Кстати, при вашей записи `OverlapSphere` в массив `coldal` будет попадать в том числе и ваш магнит, т.к. вы центром назначили его позицию. Может быть (а вдрууууууууг) дело в этом и надо писать как минимум `if (col1.attachedRigidbody != null && col1.gameObject.name != "myMagnetObjectName") { ` ....... хотя без этого вам должно было выбивать ошибку, но видимо вы ошибки игнорите))

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский на самом деле сам магнит не ригидбоди. Чтобы не двигался а просто притягивал. И из кода в fixedupdate ничего не убрано, а на старте он и не тормозит - только если в поле есть несколько объектов. Загвоздка может быть в том, что некоторые из этих тел имеют собственные скрипты с addforce - они должны преследовать цель. Но сами по себе они не висят, даже если 10 штук на сцене. А вот если поставить магнит..

Comment: Ну данный код сам по себе также не будет тормозить. Для проверки себе впихнул его - работает как и полагается. так что где-то всё вкупе тормозит... `некоторые из этих тел имеют собственные скрипты с addforce - они должны преследовать цель` а кого они должны преследовать? покажите их код. может и правда с ними вместе что происходит..... А так - проблема не воспроизводима

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вот код из преследующих тел
   `void Start () {
        
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        
        myTransform = transform;

    }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void FixedUpdate () {
        myTransform.LookAt(player.transform.position);
        rb.AddForce(myTransform.forward * enemy1speed, ForceMode.Force);
        
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так, все отлично работает:

```
public float Radius = 5f;
public float ForeceScale = 1f;

void FixedUpdate () {

    foreach (Collider item in Physics.OverlapSphere (transform.position, Radius)) {
        if (item.attachedRigidbody) {
            float ux = 0.5f / Vector3.Distance (transform.position, item.transform.position);
            item.attachedRigidbody.AddForce ((transform.position - item.transform.position) * ux * ForeceScale, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```